# running PHP application on IIS 7

Tags: php, iis, web-applications

i have a PHP application with microsoft access database, it works fine on apache server. however, i need to run it on a windows server with IIS 7, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise using Zend Server community edition.

http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/

It's free, it's reliable, it bundles zend optimizer (opcode cache) for good performance, and it has a web-based admin console. It's a simplified off-shoot of their professional server product.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can run PHP on IIS.

http://php.iis.net/

Comment: I tried running php on IIS but few things are breaking. my whole application is not running properl. require() and include() methods are breaking it seems. What should I try?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Be sure to delete your Apache configuration files (.htaccess files) as they can cause permission problems and read up on how to translate them to the IIS web.config file.

Here's a good article on that topic:

[Translate .htaccess Content to IIS web.config](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/557/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig/)

Answer (score 1):

I put a test application PHP with MS Access database on an ASP.net hosting. i treated it like a classic ASP application, it worked just fine. you just need to add "index.php" as a default document.

update (1)
i tested it locally on a vm, you may need to disable impersonation and add the following to web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```